# When can an autonomous system be written using a Hamiltonian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-systems

If I have an autonomous series of differential equations
$$\tag{1} \frac{dx_i}{dt} ~=~ A_i(x_1,...,x_n)$$
with the condition that
$$\tag{2} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}~=~0$$
in all regions of phase space, can this be written as a Hamiltonian system in terms of some generalized position and momentum coordinates?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Note that while the ODE  (1) is covariant under coordinate transformations, the divergence-free condition (2) is _not,_ unless we introduce (and specify a choice of) a volume-form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Let there be given an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ with a smooth vector field $X\in \Gamma(TM)$.
2. If $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ is some local coordinates on $M$, then the vector field takes the form
   $$\tag{A} X~=~X^i(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},$$ and one may study the  autonomous first-order ODE
   $$\tag{B} \frac{dx^i(t)}{dt}~=~ X^i(x(t)).$$
   Note that the ODE (B) transforms covariantly under change of coordinates.
3. If $X$ does not vanish in a point $p\in M$, then one may choose a local coordinate neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $p$, with local coordinates $(y^1, \ldots, y^n)$, so that
   $$\tag{C} X~=~\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1}.$$
   This procedure is sometimes called *stratification* or [*straightening out*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightening_theorem_for_vector_fields) of a vector field. It is a special case of [Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29).
4. The ODE (B) then becomes
   $$\tag{D} \frac{dy^i}{dt}~=~ \delta^i_1$$
   in the local coordinate neighborhood $U\subseteq M$.
5. If one chooses the Poisson bracket in the obvious way, i.e.
   $$\tag{E}\{y^i,y^2\}_{PB}~=~\delta^i_1,\qquad \text{etc},$$
   then one may bring the ODE (D) on Hamiltonian form
   $$ \tag{F} \frac{dy^i}{dt}~=~ \{ y^i, y^2\}_{PB}$$
   in the local coordinate neighborhood $U\subseteq M$.
6. If the dimension $n$ is even, then the Poisson bracket (E) can be chosen to be non-degenerate.
7. The question of the existence of a *global* Hamiltonian formulation is much more subtle, even for $n=2$. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53625/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51510/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Comment: What kind of conditions would be required for the existence of a global Hamiltonian formulation? I take it that analyticity of the A_i(x)'s would not be sufficient?

Comment: Analyticity of the vector field is not enough, cf. e.g. counterexample 6 in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/432672/2451) .

Comment: For the related question whether there exists a conserved energy function (rather than a full Hamiltonian formulation), see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188777/2451) Phys.SE post.