# Transformation between a dynamical system to a Hamiltonian system

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, complex-systems, poisson-brackets

Consider a dynamical system characterized by these equations

$$\dot{x}=x-xy \\
\dot{y}=-y+xy$$

If we transform $\ln(y)=q$ and $\ln(x)=p$, the system can be changed into a Hamiltonian system with $q$ and $p$ which are defined as generalized coordinates and generalized momentum.

My question: Is it always possible to find a suitable transformation to change a dynamical system into a Hamiltonian system?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175021/2451

Comment: Yeah the above link answers my question.